Persistent runtime error
Whenever I try to import a shapefile, I get the following error. I have been working without facing any issues but it bothers me because I want to fix it.

"RuntimeError: `crs=EPSG:3857&format&type=xyz&url=https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs%3Ds%26x%3D%7Bx%7D%26y%3D%7By%7D%26z%3D%7Bz%7D&zmax=20&zmin=0' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name. "

Does this happen for all vector data? Does this happen with other QGIS versions? Does this occur with a default profile?

remove the url xyz tiles - this has nothing to do with the shapefile - you can always create a new profile in QGIS. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKTRHL5YLjI

With other Qgis version, yes, for example, I am using 3.34.2-Prizren now, earlier, i was using 3.28 firenze.

This is a bug in the RasterAttributesTable plugin.
